# Custom event not raising in EventHandler .NET CORE

Tags: .net-core, eventhandler

Using .net core I'm implementing class library to push bulk emails into Email server.Email server will consume my email list and gives feedback after complete.this will take 20-30 seconds.When I got feedback from email server I need to fire method.

I have referred [this article](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/c-sharp-tutorial-understanding-c-events/) to implement event handler.But when I debug it

**EventHandler OnFeedbackReceived**

parameter is null.see image below
[image]

This is class library code.

```js
using System;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace OSH_EmailServerLibrary
{
    public static class EmailMQServerLibrary
    {        
         public static event EventHandler<EmailFeedbackEventArgs> OnFeedbackReceived;

        public static void PushToMQ(List<EmailMessage> _emailList)
        {           
        
        //
        // Long RabbitMQ msg push code here
        //             
        
         EmailMessageFeedback feedback = new EmailMessageFeedback { Description = "Completed", SuccessCount = 10, FailedCount = 0 };
         SendFeedback(feedback);
         Console.ReadLine();
        }
       
        private static EmailMessageFeedback SendFeedback(EmailMessageFeedback feedback)
        {
            if (OnFeedbackReceived != null)
            {
                OnFeedbackReceived(feedback, new 
                EmailFeedbackEventArgs(feedback));
            }
            return feedback;
        }
    }

    public class EmailFeedbackEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public EmailFeedbackEventArgs(EmailMessageFeedback _feedback)
        {
            feedback = _feedback;
        }
        public EmailMessageFeedback feedback { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is how I user it in a console application

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using OSH_EmailServerLibrary;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;

namespace EmailServerSenderSampleConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<EmailMessage> _emailList = _emails.GetAllEmailToSend();
            
            EmailMQServerLibrary.PushToMQ(_emailList);
            EmailMQServerLibrary.OnFeedbackReceived += EmailMQServerLibrary_OnFeedbackReceived;

        } 

        private static void EmailMQServerLibrary_OnFeedbackReceived(object sender, EmailFeedbackEventArgs e)
        {
          
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: it simply means the event is not subscribed.  It is not, subscribing the event a microsecond before the program terminates makes no sense.  Do it early.  And make sure the program keeps running long enough for the operation to complete.  Add Console.ReadLine().

Comment: I have changed my code as you said. But still no luck.. :(

Comment: You have to make *two* changes to fix the bugs.  "Do it early" means that you need to subscribe the event *before* you call PushToMQ().

Comment: I have added **Console.ReadLine();**  and initialize **EventHandler** top of the 
 class .check my edited question.

Comment: Yes.It worked.. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally Fixed my issue.Issue was not in my class library.Issue was I did subscribe event after PushToMQ() in my console application which is wrong..Thank you so much **@Hans Passant** helping me out.

here is my corrected answer.I think this will help others like me.

Class Library >>

```js
using System;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace OSH_EmailServerLibrary
{
    public static class EmailMQServerLibrary
    {        
         public static event EventHandler<EmailFeedbackEventArgs> OnFeedbackReceived;

        public static void PushToMQ(List<EmailMessage> _emailList)
        {           
        
        //
        // Long RabbitMQ msg push code here
        //             
        
         EmailMessageFeedback feedback = new EmailMessageFeedback { Description = "Completed", SuccessCount = 10, FailedCount = 0 };
         SendFeedback(feedback);
         Console.ReadLine();
        }
       
        private static EmailMessageFeedback SendFeedback(EmailMessageFeedback feedback)
        {
            if (OnFeedbackReceived != null)
            {
                OnFeedbackReceived(feedback, new 
                EmailFeedbackEventArgs(feedback));
            }
            return feedback;
        }
    }

    public class EmailFeedbackEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public EmailFeedbackEventArgs(EmailMessageFeedback _feedback)
        {
            feedback = _feedback;
        }
        public EmailMessageFeedback feedback { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Console Application >>

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using OSH_EmailServerLibrary;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;

namespace EmailServerSenderSampleConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<EmailMessage> _emailList = _emails.GetAllEmailToSend();
            
             EmailMQServerLibrary.OnFeedbackReceived +=
             EmailMQServerLibrary_OnFeedbackReceived; //-- worked
             EmailMQServerLibrary.PushToMQ(_emailList);
             //EmailMQServerLibrary.OnFeedbackReceived +=
             EmailMQServerLibrary_OnFeedbackReceived; -- Not working like this

        } 

        private static void EmailMQServerLibrary_OnFeedbackReceived(object sender, EmailFeedbackEventArgs e)
        {
          
        }    
    }
}
```